# Java serialization and deserialization when the state of the class changes

Tags: java, serialization

How does serialization and deserialization work in the following cases:

1. When a new field is added to the class.
2. When a non static member is converted to static
3. When a non transient field becomes transient
4. When a transient field becomes non transient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all of the cases described above, the `java.io.InvalidClassException` would be thrown in case you try to deserialize the class. The reason of this behaviour is that a *serial version* of the class used for *deserialization* does not match a *serial version* of the class used for class *serialization*. That is **default** behaviour.

This **serial version of the class** is used to verify that the serialized and deserialized objects have the same attributes and thus are compatible (which is not the case in your examples in the question).

If you don't explicitly declare a **serialVersionUID** field (of type `long`), the JVM will generate one automatically at run-time. However, if you're going to use Java serialization it is highly recommended to declare a **serialVersionUID** explicitly (because the generated one is compiler-dependent and thus may result in unexpected exceptions of `java.io.InvalidClassException`).

Suppose you explicitly declared *serialVersionUID* but you don't updated it during the changes. In your cases:

1. When a new field is added to the class. The object should de deserialized without any exceptions, a new field would have a default value.
2. When a non static member is converted to static. Your static field would have a value of corresponding non-static field.
3. When a non transient field becomes transient. Your transient field would be ignored during deserializtion and thus have a default value.
4. When a transient field becomes non transient. Because `transient` fields are ignored during serialization, this case is almost equal to the `1`st case - your field would have a default value.

Comment: If we write our own serialVersionUid rather than use the JVM provided one, wouldn't the class be considered same when we deserialize an object?

Comment: it depends whether your class is changed. if you serialized an object of class with serialVersionUID=1, then you changed the class's properties and changed serialVersionUID=2, you need to use the first version of class for deserializtion of your object (where serialVersionUID=1)

Comment: What if I change the properties of the class but don't change the serialVersionUid? How would deserialization work in that case?